# Using JSR-250 (@RolesAllowed) annotations Spring MVC and container authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have a web application that uses the Spring framework along with Spring MVC to create REST endpoints.  Authentication is provided by the container using Java EE security (specifically a security realm in Wildfly 9 backed by Active Directory), and roles are loaded from the application database.  I have a request wrapper applied by a filter to make the user details available via the normal Servlet API.

web.xml:

```xml
<web-app ... version="3.1">

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Unauthenticated Resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/favicon.ico</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/NoAccess.html</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/font/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/lib/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/partials/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All Resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>App Realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/NoAccess.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

SecurityFilter.java

```java
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "*" })
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // Don't wrap unauthenticated requests
        if (httpRequest.getRemoteUser() == null) {
            chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
            return;
        }

        Person user = this.personRepository.findByLogin(httpRequest.getRemoteUser());
        if (user != null) {
            List<String> roles = this.personRepository.getRoles(user.getId());
            HttpServletRequest wrappedRequest = new RequestWrapper(httpRequest, user, roles);
            chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, httpResponse);
        } else {
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/NoAccess.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication works and, within a controller, I can do `request.getUserPrincipal()` and `request.isUserInRole("SYSTEM_ADMIN")` and they return correctly.  Now I want to add authorisation to the application.  I want to apply the authorisation rules using the JSR-250 `@RolesPermitted` annotation on my controller methods; I don't want to have to list all of the rules in a separate configuration file/class.  A controller example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {

    ...

    @RolesAllowed({Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN, Role.DEPARTMENT_ADMIN, Role.SYSTEM_AUDITOR, Role.AUDITOR})
    @RequestMapping
    public List<Person> listPeople(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return this.personRepository.getPeople();
    }
}
```

Of course this does nothing on its own so I added a configuration class with `@EnableWebSecurity` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)`.  Now when I hit that resource I get the error `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`.  Fair enough, so I follow the example at https://gist.github.com/virgium03/86938e43219bc28632d0 but I keep getting the same error.  Seems the filter is never getting added to the filter chain.

I've read many tutorials and SO posts but they all pretty much say the same thing and don't work for me.  There must be something simple I'm missing - after all, all the information is there for Spring Security to make the authorisation decisions.  It's possible (likely?) I'm missing something simple here.  All help is muchly appreciated!

**Edit**

I have added the following code to my `SecurityFilter` class to populate the Spring security context.  It works but I feel like this isn't the ideal solution.

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken auth = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities);
auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(wrappedRequest));
auth.setAuthenticated(true);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the configured authentication provider. You are using **[PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.html)** which returns the existing Authentication token from the authenticate method. So in case if the principal is null then it ignores the requests and let other providers to authenticate it.

> authenticate
>
> public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
>                               throws AuthenticationException Authenticate the given PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken. If the
>   principal contained in the authentication object is null, the request
>   will be ignored to allow other providers to authenticate it.

Basically, you need to configure another AuthenticationProvider which will generate the Authentication token and set this token in the SecurityContext.

Comment: But looking at the source for J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter shows it creating the authentication object from the HttpRequest and putting it in the security context (via AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter).  Shouldn't this be all I need?

Comment: I looked at the source of J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and it is not creating the authentication object. It is just returning the user principal from HttpRequest.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java (the superclass of J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter)

Comment: Okay. My bad. I didn't look at the superclass. Can you debug this AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and see what you are getting in the authResult? Also, it is mentioned in the J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter documentation that there is no generic way to retrieve the credentials, as such getPreAuthenticatedCredentials method returns a fixed dummy value and this might be the reason behind AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException.

Comment: I've moved past this now (though still curious why it wasn't working) but I do appreciate your attempts to help.  See my code in the edit of the question, which I took from AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.  I set a blank credentials string but it still works.  The code to set the authentication from AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter was never called (it never hit my breakpoint) when I tested it.